# Error while using openAI key? getting RateLimitError

Tags: python, nlp, openai-api, large-language-model, py-langchain

I just created a openAI key within my project for using LLM but can't access it.

Tried this

from langchain.llms import OpenAI

```
import os
os.environ["OPEN_API_KEY"]="openAI key here"
llm=OpenAI(openai_api_key=os.environ["OPEN_API_KEY"],temperature=0.6)
text="What is the capital of India"
print(llm.predict(text))
```

[Recieved this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GevND.png)

Expecting output
[Expecting this output but recieving above attached error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH3v3.png)

Answer (score 0):

- Upgrade to a paid plan.
- Set up a paid account, add a credit or debit card.
- Set limits to not incur charges.
- Generate a new API key in user preferences.

**RateLimitError**

*Cause: You have hit your assigned rate limit.*

*Solution: Pace your requests. Read more in our Rate limit guide.*

Link to documentation: **https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/python-library-error-types**